# Unable to Display 3D model file

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I have one of my 3D models downloaded from sketchfab.com. This 3D model is in a format of`.GLTF`, When I upload the model with three.js it doesn't appear on the screen and showed me this error

`THREE.GLTFLoader: Custom UV set 1 for texture metalnessMap not yet supported.`

`THREE.GLTFLoader: Custom UV set 1 for texture roughnessMap not yet supported.`

However, on the website that I downloaded the model from, I was able to control and play with the model normally. Please if anyone has any advice, I would be highly appreciated it.

website ref : https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/high-tech-baked-my-vr-experiment-f2c941890ea941719eba7de0025e910f

my code

```
let scene, camera, renderer, controls, car;

                function init() {
                    scene = new THREE.Scene();
                    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xABABAB);

                    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
                    camera.rotation.y = 45 / 180 * Math.PI;
                    camera.position.x = 40;
                    camera.position.y = 0;
                    camera.position.z = 40;




                    hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 1);
                    scene.add(hlight);


                    directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x333333, 1);
                    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 0);
                    directionalLight.castShadow = true;
                    scene.add(directionalLight);


                    light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
                    light.position.set(-200, 0, 0);
                    scene.add(light);

                    light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
                    light2.position.set(0, 0, 200);
                    scene.add(light2);

                    light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
                    light3.position.set(200, 0, 0);
                    scene.add(light3);


                    light4 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
                    light4.position.set(0, 0, -200);
                    scene.add(light4);

                    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
                    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);



                    let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
                    loader.load('./9/scene.gltf', function (gltf) {
                        car = gltf.scene.children[0];
                        car.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
                        scene.add(gltf.scene);
                        renderer.render(scene, camera);
                        animate();

                    });


                }
                function animate() {
                    scene.rotation.y += 0.003;
                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                }
                init();
```

Comment: For what it's worth, Sketchfab does not appear to use three.js in its preview renderer. There is actually no reason to believe the Sketchfab preview actually loads a GLFT file either (I saw no obviously GLFT-related network traffic, but did see a `model_file.binz`, whatever that may be). The point is, there doesn't seem to be a link between the three.js and Sketchfab, so while your point of `THREE.GLTFLoader` not supporting those cases is legitimate, a comparison against Sketchfab's preview doesn't hold water.

Comment: Sketchfab does use its own proprietary renderer (formerly OSG), but it offers glTF as a download (not preview) format, and we normally expect the download to work in ThreeJS. But ThreeJS has a known limitation using multiple texture coordinate sets, and it sounds like the downloaded glTF is asking for something ThreeJS can't do with UVs on the roughness map.  Sadly, this model needs tweaking to work correctly in ThreeJS.